# Keeping the characters between two specific characters in fasta headers and removing the rest

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, sed, bioinformatics

I am trying to keep the characters in my fasta headers between the first and the second colon. I've failed trying with sed and awk since my coding skills are very limited.

In:

```
>TRINITY_DN10034_c0_g1:TRINITY_DN10034_c0_g1_i1:g.1561:m.1561
CCAGCGCCACGGAGGGCGAAGGCGAAGGCGGTGGTTTTGAACGATGAGGTGCCGCCGGTG
>TRINITY_DN10322_c0_g1:TRINITY_DN10322_c0_g1_i2:g.1424:m.1424
GATCCGCCTTCTATAACTGGAAAAGAAGAGGATGAGGTGCCGCCGATGAGTCTACCTTCT
```

Expected:

```
>TRINITY_DN10034_c0_g1_i1
CCAGCGCCACGGAGGGCGAAGGCGAAGGCGGTGGTTTTGAACGATGAGGTGCCGCCGGTG
>TRINITY_DN10322_c0_g1_i2
GATCCGCCTTCTATAACTGGAAAAGAAGAGGATGAGGTGCCGCCGATGAGTCTACCTTCT
```

Any help?

Comment: Rather than adding a "Thank you" comment, upvote the answer(s) that helped you, and consider ["accepting" the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) that was the most helpful in resolving your issue.  These are the best ways of showing gratitude on this site.  Accepting an answer not only marks the question as resolved, but also signals to _future readers_ that the accepted answer actually solved the issue.  More information about this is available here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`:

```
awk -F: '{ if (NF==1) { print } else { print ">"$2 } }' file
```

or a little more compressed

```
awk -F: '{ print (NF==1) ? $1 : ">"$2 }' file
```

Use field separator `:` and print the first field if the line has only one field and print `>` and the second field otherwise.

With `sed`:

```
sed 's/^>[^:]\+:\([^:]\+\).*/>\1/' file
```

Answer (score 1):

With standard `sed`:

```
$ sed '/^>/{ s/[^:]*:/>/; s/:.*//; }' file.fa
>TRINITY_DN10034_c0_g1_i1
CCAGCGCCACGGAGGGCGAAGGCGAAGGCGGTGGTTTTGAACGATGAGGTGCCGCCGGTG
>TRINITY_DN10322_c0_g1_i2
GATCCGCCTTCTATAACTGGAAAAGAAGAGGATGAGGTGCCGCCGATGAGTCTACCTTCT
```

This applies the two substitutions `s/[^:]*:/>/` and `s/:.*//` to all lines in `file.fa` that starts with a `>` (the fasta header lines).

The first substitution would replace the start of the line, up to and including the first `:` character, with `>`.

The second substitution would remove everything from the first `:` in the resulting data (the second `:` in the original line) to the end of the line.

This would leave the second `:`-delimited field, prefixed by a `>`.

---

With standard `awk`:

```
$ awk -F ':' '/^>/ { $0 = ">" $2 } { print }' file.fa
>TRINITY_DN10034_c0_g1_i1
CCAGCGCCACGGAGGGCGAAGGCGAAGGCGGTGGTTTTGAACGATGAGGTGCCGCCGGTG
>TRINITY_DN10322_c0_g1_i2
GATCCGCCTTCTATAACTGGAAAAGAAGAGGATGAGGTGCCGCCGATGAGTCTACCTTCT
```

This would use `:` as a field delimiter, and when coming across a line that starts with `>`, it would replace the complete line with `>` followed by the second `:`-delimited field.  All lines, whether modified or not, would then be printed.

Answer (score 0):

A propposed solution:

> With GNU sed

```
cut -f2 -d':' file | sed '1~2s/^/>/'
```

---

Output:

```
>TRINITY_DN10034_c0_g1_i1
CCAGCGCCACGGAGGGCGAAGGCGAAGGCGGTGGTTTTGAACGATGAGGTGCCGCCGGTG
>TRINITY_DN10322_c0_g1_i2
GATCCGCCTTCTATAACTGGAAAAGAAGAGGATGAGGTGCCGCCGATGAGTCTACCTTCT
```

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -F':' '{$0 = (NF>1 ? ">"$2 : $0)} 1' file
>TRINITY_DN10034_c0_g1_i1
CCAGCGCCACGGAGGGCGAAGGCGAAGGCGGTGGTTTTGAACGATGAGGTGCCGCCGGTG
>TRINITY_DN10322_c0_g1_i2
GATCCGCCTTCTATAACTGGAAAAGAAGAGGATGAGGTGCCGCCGATGAGTCTACCTTCT

$ awk -F':' '{sub(/>.*/,">"$2)}1' file
>TRINITY_DN10034_c0_g1_i1
CCAGCGCCACGGAGGGCGAAGGCGAAGGCGGTGGTTTTGAACGATGAGGTGCCGCCGGTG
>TRINITY_DN10322_c0_g1_i2
GATCCGCCTTCTATAACTGGAAAAGAAGAGGATGAGGTGCCGCCGATGAGTCTACCTTCT
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a multitude of ways to handle this pbm, some of them being:

```
$ cut -d: -f2 | sed -e '$!N;s/^/>/' file

$ awk -F: '/^>/{$0 = ">" $2}1' file

$ perl -F: -pale ' s/^>\K.*/$F[1]/' file

$ sed -e '
   /\n/{P;d;}
   /^>/y/:/\n/
   s/\n/&>/;//D
' file
```

**Results**

```
>TRINITY_DN10034_c0_g1_i1 
CCAGCGCCACGGAGGGCGAAGGCGAAGGCGGTGGTTTTGAACGATGAGGTGCCGCCGGTG
>TRINITY_DN10322_c0_g1_i2 
GATCCGCCTTCTATAACTGGAAAAGAAGAGGATGAGGTGCCGCCGATGAGTCTACCTTCT
```